Can't select within output cell anymore
I used to be able to select part of an output cell by mouse (for example to copy it). Now I can't anymore and get a weird plus with a circle when hovering over it and I can't select any text within the cell. See the image below:

I think this was caused by loading the package lieart.
Any idea what setting might have been changed and how I can change it back?

Actually the issue is worse. I can't display graphics anymore. It only shows -Graphics- instead of the graphic. A solution for the same problem is proposed here https://support.wolfram.com/12490 but the options mentioned are not accessible through the preference window on my Mathematica version.
13.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 7, 2022)

Possibly relevant settings:
Options[$FrontEnd, CommonDefaultFormatTypes]

returns
{CommonDefaultFormatTypes -> {Input -> StandardForm, InputInline -> StandardForm, Output -> StandardForm, OutputInline -> StandardForm, Text -> TextForm, TextInline -> TraditionalForm}}

I tried: SetOptions[$FrontEnd, CommonDefaultFormatTypes -> {"Output" -> StandardForm}] on the advice of Domen. But the issue remains.
I also tried to go through the option inspector. Changing the New Cell Default there to StandardForm and trying in a new cell keeps giving the same result.

I'm not sure that I understand full what went wrong or how I fixed it but I think I had to change the Output option to StandardForm both globally and in the specific notebook and now it is good again.
So:
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, CommonDefaultFormatTypes -> {"Output" -> StandardForm}];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 CommonDefaultFormatTypes -> {"Output" -> StandardForm}]


Have you tried Resetting Mathematica?

As you have figured it out yourself, something changed your default format type of the output cells. You can check this by evaluating:
Options[$FrontEnd, CommonDefaultFormatTypes]
(* {CommonDefaultFormatTypes -> {"Input" -> StandardForm, 
   "InputInline" -> StandardForm, "Output" -> StandardForm, 
   "OutputInline" -> StandardForm, "Text" -> TextForm, 
   "TextInline" -> TraditionalForm}} *)

You probably have some OutputForm there, which should instead be StandardForm.
Follow these instructions to change the settings via Option Inspector, or programmatically with:
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, CommonDefaultFormatTypes -> {"Output" -> StandardForm}]


Thanks. Unfortunately this didn't resolve my issue. It remains the same after running that command (or changing the setting by hand in the Option Inspector).

Thanks. I think I fixed it in the end by setting the Output to StandardForm both globally and in the notebook. So in addition to your answer I also ran:
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],       CommonDefaultFormatTypes -> {"Output" -> StandardForm}]

@Kvothe, great!
